# Installing on SSD with personal files on HDD

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, ssd

I’m somewhat new to the Linux world. I have a desktop with a 240GB SSD and a 4TB  HDD. I would like to set my system up where I have Ubuntu on my SSD, and all my personal files (Games, Programs Pictures etc) on my HDD.

I originally plugged in just my SSD and chose the **Erase the disk and install Ubuntu** option but when I connected and reformatted my HDD I needed to be root any time I wanted to write anything to it.

Then, I tried installing with both drives attached. I put my root and boot partitions on my SSD and the `/home` partition on my HDD. When I did this GRUB would not install. My SSD was designated sdb and my HDD was sda my partitions on my SSD were / 8000MB /Boot 1000MB and on my HDD /Home 4TB.

Is there a better partitioning scheme, or can I do what I did the first time to install, and change the permissions on my HDD so I don’t need to elevate to root any time I want to write or delete something?

I also created a 16GB SWAP partition on my SSD as I have 16GB of RAM.

Comment: You asked two questions,  you can not install grub on your SSD and  you  want to login as administrator `root` account.

Comment: Why not simply create sda partition for 240GB SSD and sdb partition for 4TB HDD? You dont have to worry about being root if you already know the password to it. Just format and install OS on SSD then simply leave the HDD plugged in. If you really need to erase it use gparted.

Comment: If installing in UEFI boot mode you need an ESP, I like to have one on every drive even if not currently used. Drive must be gpt partitioned. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu With a 4TB drive I would not have just one partition. Your SSD is large enough for /home, but then you can have data partitions on HDD. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk I suggest an install on HDD, also.

Comment: I suggest that the easiest way to do this is to first install Ubuntu on your SDD only. This lets you take all the default install options. Once its up and running, you can format your HDD and mount it under /home.